# Can there be a set which is finite but uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sorry for asking such a absurd question. I'm currently, revisiting fundamental of mathematics in little spare time I have and I stumbled upon this little messy thought.

> > Can there be a set which is finite but uncountable?

I know, that it is not possible. But I am looking for some reasonable explantion.

Further,

Does this very question violets the definition of sets? If it does, then which part of the definition of set is violated?

e.g. patch of water on a ground. You can see it as a finite mini water body, but we can't count how much water it is. Water is uncountable (so does any other liquid).

Again, I am sorry. I am mixing grammatical definition of countable and uncountable nouns with concept of countable and uncountable set theory.

And this question is entirely for the purpose of brain storming.

NOTE: One can say, count the molecule of H<sub>2</sub>O, but water is not equal to H<sub>2</sub>O, it bit more than that, it does contain other minerals. Also, how do we even count water molecules, if we don't know the related physical quantities: Volume, density, type of water etc.

Comment: If you really want to ask whether we can count mass nouns, it might be more appropriate for philosophy or linguistics, but I'm not even sure it would be on-topic there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on Lee's answer, I think you are confusing a few things here.

Water is not a set. But perhaps by patch of water on the ground, you mean the set of all points that belong to that patch of water, $P\in \mathbb R^2$, which has positive area $\oint_P dx\ dy>0$.

Then yes, P, which is the set of all points within P, is uncountable $|P|=|\{(x, y) | (x, y) \in P\}|=2^{\aleph_0}$.

But if you see this as a single patch, then there being one patch it is of course countable $|\{P\}|=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is about mathematical formalities, not about a patch of water on the ground or anything like that.

By definition, to say that a set $A$ is countable means that either $A$ is finite or there exists a bijection between $A$ and the natural numbers. And by definition, to say that $A$ is uncountable means that $A$ is not countable.

So, applying those definitions, no finite set is uncountable.